# Does the recurrence $I_n=\frac{n-1}nI_{n-2}$ for $I_n=\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^nx\,dx$ have anything to do with Fourier series?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, recurrence-relations, fourier-transform

I was finding the recurrence relation for the following integral: $$I_n = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^n(x)\,dx$$ I derived the following relation: $$I_{n} = \frac{n-1}{n}\cdot I_{n-2}$$

What I than did was to plot the $I_n$ as the function of $n$. At first I didn't restrict $n$ to be natural number, which is not what is assumed in those types recurrence relations, as far as I was taught. This resulted in the graph shown at [this Desmos link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/favu5borsh), and a function $I(n)$ that looked like some kind of irrational function, at least from $x\in (-1,+\infty)$.

Immediately, this reminded me of the Fourier series, but that's as far as I went with my knowledge. I am wondering

> Is my assumption that this has to do something with the Fourier series right, and if so, is there any method that could be used to get a more closed-form expression of the function that was transformed?

I wouldn't expect that to be true for every function, but having even a few examples of something like that could be interesting to me.

To recap, my question is:

> Does this have anything to do with the Fourier transform, and if so, could the transform be reversed, in such a way that we get the original function back?

Thanks to everyone on their answers in advance!

Comment: Everything has to do with everything, and yes a Fourier transform [can be reversed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem). Now what is your question, really?

Comment: That would be the answer, sir. Thank you! I am also wondering does the derivation process stay valid if i assume n is a real number? Since the antiderivative of the polynomial is defined for any real powers, I would assume so.

Comment: Also, is there a way to know is the function that I am graphing really a radical, or it just resembles one

Comment: Well, you may rewrite your recurrence relation in a closed form using factorials, and then generalize those to non-integer $n$ using the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), and that supposedly would be your graph (which would still require a rigorous proof, which I guess can be made via Beta function).

Comment: I get it, thanks!!

Comment: Using the relation $ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^p(x)cos^q(x) dx =  \frac{ \Gamma(\frac{p+1}{2})  \Gamma(\frac{q+1}{2}) }{2 \Gamma(\frac{p+q}{2}+1)} $ and setting $ q = 0 $ gives the required integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$I_n=\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^n(x)\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\ \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}\ ,\quad\Re(n)>-1.\tag{1}$$

So

$$I_n=\frac{n-1}{n}\ I_{n-2}\tag{2}$$

follows from the properties of the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Comment: See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+cos%28x%29%5En+from+0+to+pi%2F2 for evaluation of the integral in formula (1).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Finally, I have the answer I was looking for!

Comment: From the R(n) > -1 I notice that this extends the original integral for some complex values of n(real part greater than -1). This means valid value of n could be 1+i as well?

Comment: @ĐumićBranislav The integral is only valid for $Re(n)>-1$, but for the function $f(n)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\ \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}$ the relationship $f(n)=\frac{(n-1)}{n} f(n-2)$ is valid for all $n\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: But the formula in terms of Gamma function is not because it's not defined for n<-1 ? We have not studied the Gamma function at the Uni so my knowledge on it is limited

Comment: @ĐumićBranislav I believe the integral only converges for $\Re(n)>-1$ (see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+cos%28x%29%5E%28-3%2F2%29+from+0+to+pi%2F2), but the gamma function is defined for all complex numbers except the non-positive integers, so I should have noted that $f(n)=\frac{(n-1)}{n} f(n-2)$ has exceptions when a non-positive integer argument is encountered in the evaluation of $f(n)$ and/or $f(n-2)$.

Comment: I understand it now! Thank you very much!